# Formula to count number of cells with a name in if it matches this month

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google

looking for a formula that will count names in one column if it matches another date column which is this month.

Column A - Name
Column B - date
Column C, Row 1 = todays date

The formula would look at C1 for the date and count all names in column a if it matches this month from C1

Hope this makes sense, apologies if I've not explained very well!

Basically looking for a count of names if the month is August

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to have a cell with the value of `today()`.
In fact, the formula takes into consideration only columns `A` and `B` and it is this:

```
=counta(ifna(filter(A2:A,month(B2:B)=month(today()))))
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much